# How to show times and dates in Outlook 2013 "received" column?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I upgraded to Outlook 2013, and missing the 2010 display of date and time in "received" column.
In 2013 it shows either time or date (for older emails), but not both.

Any idea how to restore to 2010 date and time view of the column?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- Right click on the `Received` column header
- Click `View settings`
- Click `Format columns`
- Choose `Received` from `Available Fields`
- Pick the format you want.

Comment: The "Format columns" options let you choose how to show a date, or how to show a time, but there is no option showing both date & time.

Comment: From a comment by a deleted user on another answer: _Once you are on the final window with the Format drop-down menu, scroll up until you see the option for date and time._ I don't know if it's true.

Comment: Dammit! it is there if you scroll up. Outlook 2016. spent far too long on this.

Answer (score 12):

- Go to View tab Click on 'View Settings' button (second from the left)
- Click 'Format Columns'
- In 'Available Fields' on the left highlight 'Received'
- From the 'Format' drop-down menu, choose how you want it displayed. I have Tue 8/12/2014 12:45 PM selected.
- Click OK
- Click OK again.

Answer (score 3):

However, the answer by trpt4him does not allow you to show the seconds.
[This SU answer](https://superuser.com/questions/809157/how-to-include-the-second-in-outlook-received-time-hhmmss) shows a way to do show them.

1. Create a new, custom column, as outlined [here](https://superuser.com/questions/809157/how-to-include-the-second-in-outlook-received-time-hhmmss).
2. Then use this formula: `Format([Received],"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")`
   This shows as:

   > 2014-08-22 10:59:03

Answer (score 3):

None of these methods were working. I tried them all. In the column showing the list of current emails in the folder, I found no way to change the defaulted method the Outlooks shows the sent date/time. It is always the time for current day, day and hour/min for yesterday, and day/date only for anything older than that. No matter how I changed the formatting for the SENT display, it would not change. Creating a custom column did not work as Outlook would not show the created column. I did finally stumble on one thing. In the current shown email header, there is an arrow carot on the bottom right of the header. If you click it to expand the header to maximum size, then you can get the formatting of the sent date/time in the header to match what you need. But only in the current open email in the read pane.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to change this too.

I right clicked atop the Received column area
Went into View Settings
Other Settings...
Under Column Headings and Rows at the top I un-ticked Automatic Column Sizing.

The day, date, month year and time all just popped up then for me. Didn't have to widen any columns or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer given by trpt4him doesn't work:  the "Format columns" options let you choose how to show a date, or how to show a time, but there is no option showing both.

A partial solution:  change the reading pane.

Leave the "Format columns" option at the default ("Best fit").  Click "View", then in the "Layout" grouping you'll find "Reading Pane".  Set that to Bottom, or to Off.  Then, resize the "RECEIVED" column, so it's large enough that "Best fit" will always include the day, date, and time.

(For the record, other options that may seem obvious:  drag & shrink the reading page to give "Best fit" more room, or right-click the desktop, select "screen resolution", and set the monitor size to larger numbers.)

Comment: Actually, the answer given by trpt4him can show date **and** time. Once you are on the final window with the **Format** drop-down menu, scroll up until you see the option for date and time.

Answer (score -1):

After your upgrade from Outlook 2010 to 2013, you should reset your view settings and your good

> View » Current View » Customize current View » Reset Current View

Answer (score -1):

Easy fix for me that wasn't any of the above!

Got to the ribbon tab "View". Click the icon with 2 gears "View Settings". On the popup click "Columns" and under the option "Mazimum number of lines in compact mode" change the number from "2" to "3". BOOM. Times and dates show up on the list and in the reading pane.