# Stop Outlook from showing folder name in received column

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm using Outlook in Office Home and Business 2010. I have Show As Conversation enabled, so I can see all emails in the thread in my inbox. However, the Received Time column shows the subfolder name instead of the received time:
[Outlook Received Time Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/686G0.png).

As I was writing this post, I started taking screenshots, and had the idea that emails I sent weren't received by me, which is why it can't display the time. So I switched the column to Sent Time instead. This is where it gets weird / annoying - while I had the column chooser open, it worked as expected:
[Outlook Received and Sent Time Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0JIR.png), but when I closed the field chooser, the Sent Time column behaved exactly as the Received Time column (showing the folder name instead of the time): [Outlook Sent Time Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p46c.png)

How do I get the time in that column? I can see some (warped?) logic in displaying the subfolder name to indicate that it's not in this folder, but:

- it's already in a different font color and style, so I can see that, and
- I've got the folder name shown in another column!

Is there any way to fix this, other than leaving the Field Chooser open? :/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Update: it's not about having the Field Chooser open, Sent Time is showing correctly if BOTH columns are shown, even with the Field Chooser closed. So I need to display unnecessary information to be able to get the information I do want to see, and crowd my interface more than it needs to be. :/  My solution is to display both, but set the Received column to a minimal width, to optimise display space.

Comment: I have the same happening. For me this is a bug in the conversation view, as I cannot find a case where this might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can!!

Just create a **custom column** as detailed on [this other SU answer](https://superuser.com/questions/809157/how-to-include-the-second-in-outlook-received-time-hhmmss), and it will **always** display de date. Working in Outlook 2016.

Comment: Note that you cannot use a custom column for sorting, which is a major drawback of this answer,

Answer (score -1):

If there are only specific users facing this issue, I suspect this issue is due to an interrupted Outlook profile or Office installation. Please try to [re-create an Outlook profile](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-outlook-profile-f544c1ba-3352-4b3b-be0b-8d42a540459d) for this user or perform a [repair/update with Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b).